# Materialize CSS - passing data to sideNav

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, materialize

I'm using [materializeCss](http://materializecss.com/) for my latest project and I have a problem.

I use [sideNav](http://materializecss.com/side-nav.html) to open a 'modal' inside of which is a contact form.

This contact form should be used in multiple occasions and different informations should be prefilled depending on which button does user click.

Let me explain it in an example:

If user clicks on `Send Message` then the forms input title should be something like

```
<input type='text' id='title' name='title' readonly value="General message">
```

and if user clicks on button `Request Candy` then this input should be something like

```
<input type='text' id='title' name='title' readonly value="I want candies!">
```

Since the `sideNav` opens by clicking on an element of type

```
<a href="#" data-activates="slide-out" class="button-collapse"><i class="material-icons">menu</i></a>
```

I had an idea to react on the click as

```
$(document).on('click', '.button-collapse', function() {
    console.log('got it!');
    $('#title').val('My custom message from data-* or something..');
})
```

but this doesn't work since probably materialize hijacks click events on these `a.button-collapse`'s. I don't even get the console log `got it!`.

Does anybody know a way to pass some data to the newly open sideNav?

**UPDATE:**

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rz4vmfhe/15/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<input>` is a "head only" tag - has no closing `</input>` and yet element has no content.

So you markup shall look like

```
<input type='text' id='title' name='title' value='General message' readonly></input>
```

UPDATE:

Change to this:

```
$('.button-collapse').on('click', function() {
    $('#title').val($(this).data('title'));
    console.log('I have been clicked');
  })
```

and it will work. Seems like document or framework is consuming the event so you cannot handle it on that level.

Comment: Yes thanks, I've updated that, writing code from my head. Fiddle is comming.

Comment: Something may call `Event.stopPropagation()` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation so it will not bubble up to document level.

Answer (score 0):

Theres a bug in your event handler, this will work.

```js
$('.button-collapse').sideNav({
  menuWidth: 200, // Default is 240
  edge: 'right', // Choose the horizontal origin
  //closeOnClick: true, // Closes side-nav on <a> clicks, useful for Angular/Meteor
  //draggable: true // Choose whether you can drag to open on touch screens
});


$(".button-collapse").click((e) => {
  $('#title').val($(e.target).data('title'));
})
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.8/css/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.8/js/materialize.min.js"></script>



<ul id="slide-out" class="side-nav">
  <input type="text" id="title" name="title" value="my Title">
</ul>

<a href="#" data-activates="slide-out" class="button-collapse" data-title="Option one title">Option 1</a>
<a href="#" data-activates="slide-out" class="button-collapse" data-title="Option two title">Option 2</a>
```

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what @c-smile said. I'm having problems understanding this up/down propagation of events but this will work in my case.